# Promise usage in different controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When entering my application the user sends some socket requests to subscribe to specific rooms. I have a service for this:

```
@app.factory 'CurrentConnections', ($q) ->
return {
data: [],

init: ->
  self = @
  io.socket.on 'connect', ->
    io.socket.get '/connections/subscribe', (data, jwr) ->
      self.setInitialData data
```

A different controller will use this data;

```
@app.controller 'CurrentlyOnlinePanelCtrl', ($scope, $element, CurrentConnections) ->
    CurrentConnections.getInitialData() # ...
```

But `getInitialData` is empty when called, since data is not loaded at this point.

I haven't used promises so far, but I guess they'd work here? If so, does the promise change me `set` or my `get` method?

Comment: Haven't used angular before, but for a promise to work in this setup, `getInitialData()` would return a promise that you could chain off of so `CurrentConnections.getInitialData().then()`. If you were to stash a promise in `initialData` (like doing `self.setInitialData dataPromise`) you could potentially do `CurrentConnections.getInitialData().then()` and that _should_ work. The only other thing I'm unsure about is how the data would stream after the socket was opened.

Comment: Modified my `getInitialData` to look like, https://gist.github.com/nehalist/d9315ad2ea2e3a5942dcdef2a3da6745. But still not working, and I have no idea why.

Comment: So that logic you're going to want to get in your fetch. The promise is used more or less to deferr async functionality. So you might want the promise in your setInitialData... so that it looks something like: https://jsfiddle.net/emub1onf/ . Alternatively, you could poll getInitialData until the data is there.